# Compressing and Encoding the contents of a file in python

Tags: python, encode, zlib

I am trying to compress and encode the contents of a file in python using the zlib.compress() and encode('base64') as follows:

```
teststr = zlib.compress("/root/scriptss/test.sh").encode('base64')
print teststr
```

When I decompress and decode this as follows,

```
revstr = zlib.decompress(teststr.decode('base64'))
print revstr
```

I get the string `/root/scriptss/test.sh` as the output and not the contents of the file. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *read* the file:

```
with open("/root/scriptss/test.sh") as inputfile:
    teststr = zlib.compress(inputfile.read()).encode('base64')
    print teststr
```

`zlib.compress()` takes a string to compress, not a filename.